# Interpretation lmer output with interaction

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have performed this model:

`M1 <- lmer(RNA_V ~ time + GENDER + time:GENDER + (time | PATIENT), df, REML=T)`

I need to know if the two genders have different viral decay (relation between time and RNA in a longitudinal dataframe with several RNA inputs and times for each subject.

The results were:
[image: lm]

Considering that the association with time and RNA is negative (with more time elapsed, less RNA). 
The gender==2 condition increases the effect of this association 0.07 times? (almost significant p=0.058). So, the gender==2 presented sharper viral decay curve (more negative), am I right?

Answer (score 4):

The interpretation of the coefficients is as follows:

- `time = -0.16462` denotes how much the average RNA viral load changes (here decreases) with unit of time for subjects with `GENDER = 1`.
- `GENDER2 = -0.32416` denotes the difference in average RNA viral loads between subjects with `GENDER = 2` and `GENDER = 1`.
- `time:GENDER2 = 0.07643` denotes the difference between subjects with `GENDER = 2` and `GENDER = 1` in the average change of RNA viral load per unit of time. That is, the average RNA viral load changes with `time + time:GENDER2 = - 0.16462 + 0.07643` per unit of time for subjects with `GENDER = 2`.